# Open python2.7 and python3.9 interpreters at the same time in c++ embedded python

Tags: python, c++, cpython

I have C++ project. I need to run python modules from c++ code through C Python API. Some of these modules support python2.7 and other support python3.9. Is it possible to open 2 interpreters with python2.7 and python3.9 to run code from all these modules?

I didn't find how to implement this.

Comment: This looks like an *XY Problem* that makes no sense. Why do you need that? Port your *Python 2.7* (dead for 3.5+ years !!!) modules to *v3.9* first.

Comment: i have a module with peach (supports ONLY python2.7) and one module with tensorflow (which supports ONLY python3.x.x). I want to open 2 interpreters to run both modules.